# How to play a local video with Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have a short `mp4` video file that I've added to my current Xcode6 Beta project.

**I want to play the video in my app.**

After hours searching, I can't find anything remotely helpful. Is there a way to accomplish this with Swift or do you have to use Objective-C? 
Can I get pointed in the right direction? I can't be the only one wondering this.

Comment: since You can do this in Cocoa you can do it in Swift

Answer (score 324, accepted):

Sure you can use Swift!

### 1. Adding the video file

Add the video (lets call it `video.m4v`) to your Xcode project

### 2. Checking your video is into the Bundle

Open the `Project Navigator` <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

Then select `your project root` > `your Target` > `Build Phases` > `Copy Bundle Resources`.

Your video **MUST** be here. If it's not, then you should add it using the plus button

[image]

### 3. Code

Open your View Controller and write this code.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        playVideo()
    }

    private func playVideo() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType:"m4v") else {
            debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
            return
        }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        present(playerController, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most imp part of this solution is to check that field "Add To targets"-> Project name when we copy that resource to our project.  Thanks this solution worked for me..

Comment: The MPMoviePlayerController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9. (The MPMoviePlayerViewController class is also formally deprecated.) To play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the AVPictureInPictureController or AVPlayerViewController class from the AVKit framework, or the WKWebView class from WebKit.

[Apple reference guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html)

Comment: can you please check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952056/video-file-not-playing-that-is-on-server

Comment: Having trouble with this in latest xcode beta 7.2 - `initializer for conditional binding must have optional type not nsurl`

Comment: That's why the `NSURL` initialiser no longer returns an optional. Remove this line `url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path),` and on the next line replace the variable `url` with `NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)`.

Comment: @appzYourLife great answer! but how can I play streaming video using your solution on swift 2.1? I searched the web but i couldn't play streaming video with avplayer !

Comment: hi @appzYourLife any chance you could help on this question about capturing video? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704032/swift-video-records-at-one-size-but-renders-at-wrong-size

Comment: One question , as the ViewController screen will always create a new instance when the screen appears on screen ... does this mean that the firstAppear Bool will always be true ?

Comment: hello my application is only supported portrait mode if i am starting video in landscape mode and when i am click on  done button my view remains in landscape mode but i want that view in portrait mode because my application is only supported portrait mode  so how to do in swift????

Comment: this did not work for me.  AVPlayerViewController does not exist.  If it has to be user defined vc, then it should not prefix with AV -- confusing.

Comment: @mobibob Of course [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller)  exists :-) Did you `import AVKit`?

Comment: @LucaAngeletti i was experiencing a problem with Xcode auto-complete.  Once i fixed that, AVPlayerViewController showed and compiled.  I did not think to update my comment.

Comment: @LucaAngeletti I want to play my local system .mp4 file on my real device. The location of the mp4 file is Desktop or Network.

Comment: @Rex Please [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a new question

Comment: tip: I made a stupid mistake to use `URL(string: fileString)` that will never load the video file. Be careful.

Comment: Thank you. I don't why after all this time Apple has not automated this as for Assets.

Answer (score 35):

another Swift 3 Example. The provided solution did not work for me.

```
private func playVideo(from file:String) {
    let file = file.components(separatedBy: ".")

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file[0], ofType:file[1]) else {
        debugPrint( "\(file.joined(separator: ".")) not found")
        return
    }
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
}
```

useage:

```
playVideo(from: "video.extension")
```

Note:
Check **Copy Bundle Resources** under **Build Phases** to ensure that the video is available to the Project.

Comment: This solution works with other layers together, it is a better solution than the majority voted one, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

**Here a solution for Swift 5.2**

PlayerView.swift:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class PlayerView: UIView {

    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    // Override UIView property
    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

VideoPlayer.swift

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

protocol VideoPlayerDelegate {
    func downloadedProgress(progress:Double)
    func readyToPlay()
    func didUpdateProgress(progress:Double)
    func didFinishPlayItem()
    func didFailPlayToEnd()
}

let videoContext: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = nil

class VideoPlayer : NSObject {

    private var assetPlayer:AVPlayer?
    private var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
    private var urlAsset:AVURLAsset?
    private var videoOutput:AVPlayerItemVideoOutput?

    private var assetDuration:Double = 0
    private var playerView:PlayerView?

    private var autoRepeatPlay:Bool = true
    private var autoPlay:Bool = true

    var delegate:VideoPlayerDelegate?

    var playerRate:Float = 1 {
        didSet {
            if let player = assetPlayer {
                player.rate = playerRate > 0 ? playerRate : 0.0
            }
        }
    }

    var volume:Float = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            if let player = assetPlayer {
                player.volume = volume > 0 ? volume : 0.0
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Init

    convenience init(urlAsset:NSURL, view:PlayerView, startAutoPlay:Bool = true, repeatAfterEnd:Bool = true) {
        self.init()

        playerView = view
        autoPlay = startAutoPlay
        autoRepeatPlay = repeatAfterEnd

        if let playView = playerView, let playerLayer = playView.layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
            playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        }
        initialSetupWithURL(url: urlAsset)
        prepareToPlay()
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    // MARK: - Public

    func isPlaying() -> Bool {
        if let player = assetPlayer {
            return player.rate > 0
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func seekToPosition(seconds:Float64) {
        if let player = assetPlayer {
            pause()
            if let timeScale = player.currentItem?.asset.duration.timescale {
                player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, preferredTimescale: timeScale), completionHandler: { (complete) in
                    self.play()
                })
            }
        }
    }

    func pause() {
        if let player = assetPlayer {
            player.pause()
        }
    }

    func play() {
        if let player = assetPlayer {
            if (player.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay) {
                player.play()
                player.rate = playerRate
            }
        }
    }

    func cleanUp() {
        if let item = playerItem {
            item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
            item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges")
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        assetPlayer = nil
        playerItem = nil
        urlAsset = nil
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    private func prepareToPlay() {
        let keys = ["tracks"]
        if let asset = urlAsset {
            asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.startLoading()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    private func startLoading(){
        var error:NSError?
        guard let asset = urlAsset else {return}
        let status:AVKeyValueStatus = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "tracks", error: &error)

        if status == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded {
            assetDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)

            let videoOutputOptions = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)]
            videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: videoOutputOptions)
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

            if let item = playerItem {
                item.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .initial, context: videoContext)
                item.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: [.new, .old], context: videoContext)

                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didFailedToPlayToEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

                if let output = videoOutput {
                    item.add(output)

                    item.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithm.varispeed
                    assetPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

                    if let player = assetPlayer {
                        player.rate = playerRate
                    }

                    addPeriodicalObserver()
                    if let playView = playerView, let layer = playView.layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
                        layer.player = assetPlayer
                        print("player created")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addPeriodicalObserver() {
        let timeInterval = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 1)

        if let player = assetPlayer {
            player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: timeInterval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (time) in
                self.playerDidChangeTime(time: time)
            })
        }
    }

    private func playerDidChangeTime(time:CMTime) {
        if let player = assetPlayer {
            let timeNow = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
            let progress = timeNow / assetDuration

            delegate?.didUpdateProgress(progress: progress)
        }
    }

    @objc private func playerItemDidReachEnd() {
        delegate?.didFinishPlayItem()

        if let player = assetPlayer {
            player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            if autoRepeatPlay == true {
                play()
            }
        }
    }

    @objc private func didFailedToPlayToEnd() {
        delegate?.didFailPlayToEnd()
    }

    private func playerDidChangeStatus(status:AVPlayer.Status) {
        if status == .failed {
            print("Failed to load video")
        } else if status == .readyToPlay, let player = assetPlayer {
            volume = player.volume
            delegate?.readyToPlay()

            if autoPlay == true && player.rate == 0.0 {
                play()
            }
        }
    }

    private func moviewPlayerLoadedTimeRangeDidUpdated(ranges:Array<NSValue>) {
        var maximum:TimeInterval = 0
        for value in ranges {
            let range:CMTimeRange = value.timeRangeValue
            let currentLoadedTimeRange = CMTimeGetSeconds(range.start) + CMTimeGetSeconds(range.duration)
            if currentLoadedTimeRange > maximum {
                maximum = currentLoadedTimeRange
            }
        }
        let progress:Double = assetDuration == 0 ? 0.0 : Double(maximum) / assetDuration

        delegate?.downloadedProgress(progress: progress)
    }

    deinit {
        cleanUp()
    }

    private func initialSetupWithURL(url:NSURL) {
        let options = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : true]
        urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url as URL, options: options)
    }

    // MARK: - Observations
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        if context == videoContext {
            if let key = keyPath {
                if key == "status", let player = assetPlayer {
                    playerDidChangeStatus(status: player.status)
                } else if key == "loadedTimeRanges", let item = playerItem {
                    moviewPlayerLoadedTimeRangeDidUpdated(ranges: item.loadedTimeRanges)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private var playerView: PlayerView = PlayerView()
private var videoPlayer:VideoPlayer?
```

and inside `viewDidLoad()`:

```
view.addSubview(playerView)
preparePlayer()

// set Constraints (if you do it purely in code)
playerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
playerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
playerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
playerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10.0).isActive = true
playerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
```

```
private func preparePlayer() {
    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "my video", ofType: "mp4") {
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        videoPlayer = VideoPlayer(urlAsset: fileURL, view: playerView)
        if let player = videoPlayer {
            player.playerRate = 0.67
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This example helps if you want to play the video just in a view instead of creating another full screen ViewController. Unlike using AVPlayerViewController.

Answer (score 15):

U can setup `AVPlayer` in another way, that open for u full customization of your video Player screen

**Swift 2.3**

1. Create `UIView` subclass for playing video (basically u can use any `UIView` object and only needed is `AVPlayerLayer`. I setup in this way because it much clearer for me)

   ```
   import AVFoundation
   import UIKit

   class PlayerView: UIView {

   override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
       return AVPlayerLayer.self
   }

   var player:AVPlayer? {
       set {
           if let layer = layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
               layer.player = player
           }
       }
       get {
           if let layer = layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
               return layer.player
           } else {
               return nil
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Setup your player

   ```
   import AVFoundation
   import Foundation

   protocol VideoPlayerDelegate {
       func downloadedProgress(progress:Double)
       func readyToPlay()
       func didUpdateProgress(progress:Double)
       func didFinishPlayItem()
       func didFailPlayToEnd()
   }

   let videoContext:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = nil

   class VideoPlayer : NSObject {

       private var assetPlayer:AVPlayer?
       private var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
       private var urlAsset:AVURLAsset?
       private var videoOutput:AVPlayerItemVideoOutput?

       private var assetDuration:Double = 0
       private var playerView:PlayerView?

       private var autoRepeatPlay:Bool = true
       private var autoPlay:Bool = true

       var delegate:VideoPlayerDelegate?

       var playerRate:Float = 1 {
           didSet {
               if let player = assetPlayer {
                   player.rate = playerRate > 0 ? playerRate : 0.0
               }
           }
       }

       var volume:Float = 1.0 {
           didSet {
               if let player = assetPlayer {
                   player.volume = volume > 0 ? volume : 0.0
               }
           }
       }

       // MARK: - Init

       convenience init(urlAsset:NSURL, view:PlayerView, startAutoPlay:Bool = true, repeatAfterEnd:Bool = true) {
           self.init()

           playerView = view
           autoPlay = startAutoPlay
           autoRepeatPlay = repeatAfterEnd

           if let playView = playerView, let playerLayer = playView.layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
               playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
           }
           initialSetupWithURL(urlAsset)
           prepareToPlay()
       }

       override init() {
           super.init()
       }

       // MARK: - Public

       func isPlaying() -> Bool {
           if let player = assetPlayer {
               return player.rate > 0
           } else {
               return false
           }
       }

       func seekToPosition(seconds:Float64) {
           if let player = assetPlayer {
               pause()
               if let timeScale = player.currentItem?.asset.duration.timescale {
                   player.seekToTime(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, timeScale), completionHandler: { (complete) in
                       self.play()
                   })
               }
           }
       }

       func pause() {
           if let player = assetPlayer {
               player.pause()
           }
       }

       func play() {
           if let player = assetPlayer {
               if (player.currentItem?.status == .ReadyToPlay) {
                   player.play()
                   player.rate = playerRate
               }
           }
       }

       func cleanUp() {
           if let item = playerItem {
               item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
               item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges")
           }
           NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
           assetPlayer = nil
           playerItem = nil
           urlAsset = nil
       }

       // MARK: - Private

       private func prepareToPlay() {
           let keys = ["tracks"]
           if let asset = urlAsset {
               asset.loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys(keys, completionHandler: {
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                       self.startLoading()
                   })
               })
           }
       }

       private func startLoading(){
           var error:NSError?
           guard let asset = urlAsset else {return}
           let status:AVKeyValueStatus = asset.statusOfValueForKey("tracks", error: &error)

           if status == AVKeyValueStatus.Loaded {
               assetDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)

               let videoOutputOptions = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)]
               videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: videoOutputOptions)
               playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

               if let item = playerItem {
                   item.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .Initial, context: videoContext)
                   item.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: [.New, .Old], context: videoContext)

                   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
                   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didFailedToPlayToEnd), name: AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)

                   if let output = videoOutput {
                       item.addOutput(output)

                       item.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed
                       assetPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

                       if let player = assetPlayer {
                           player.rate = playerRate
                       }

                       addPeriodicalObserver()
                       if let playView = playerView, let layer = playView.layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
                           layer.player = assetPlayer
                           print("player created")
                       }
                   }
               }
           }        
       }

       private func addPeriodicalObserver() {
           let timeInterval = CMTimeMake(1, 1)

           if let player = assetPlayer {
               player.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(timeInterval, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue(), usingBlock: { (time) in
                   self.playerDidChangeTime(time)
               })
           }
       }

       private func playerDidChangeTime(time:CMTime) {
           if let player = assetPlayer {
               let timeNow = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
               let progress = timeNow / assetDuration

               delegate?.didUpdateProgress(progress)
           }
       }

       @objc private func playerItemDidReachEnd() {
           delegate?.didFinishPlayItem()

           if let player = assetPlayer {
               player.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
               if autoRepeatPlay == true {
                   play()
               }
           }
       }

       @objc private func didFailedToPlayToEnd() {
           delegate?.didFailPlayToEnd()
       }

       private func playerDidChangeStatus(status:AVPlayerStatus) {
           if status == .Failed {
               print("Failed to load video")
           } else if status == .ReadyToPlay, let player = assetPlayer {
               volume = player.volume
               delegate?.readyToPlay()

               if autoPlay == true && player.rate == 0.0 {
                   play()
               }
           }
       }

       private func moviewPlayerLoadedTimeRangeDidUpdated(ranges:Array<NSValue>) {
           var maximum:NSTimeInterval = 0
           for value in ranges {
               let range:CMTimeRange = value.CMTimeRangeValue
               let currentLoadedTimeRange = CMTimeGetSeconds(range.start) + CMTimeGetSeconds(range.duration)
               if currentLoadedTimeRange > maximum {
                   maximum = currentLoadedTimeRange
               }
           }
           let progress:Double = assetDuration == 0 ? 0.0 : Double(maximum) / assetDuration

           delegate?.downloadedProgress(progress)
       }

       deinit {
           cleanUp()
       }

       private func initialSetupWithURL(url:NSURL) {
           let options = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : true]
           urlAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: options)
       }

       // MARK: - Observations

       override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
           if context == videoContext {
               if let key = keyPath {
                   if key == "status", let player = assetPlayer {
                       playerDidChangeStatus(player.status)
                   } else if key == "loadedTimeRanges", let item = playerItem {
                       moviewPlayerLoadedTimeRangeDidUpdated(item.loadedTimeRanges)
                   }
               }
           }
       }

   }
   ```
3. Usage:

assume u have view

```
@IBOutlet private weak var playerView: PlayerView!
private var videoPlayer:VideoPlayer?
```

and in `viewDidLoad()`

```
    private func preparePlayer() {
        if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("intro", ofType: "m4v") {
            let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            videoPlayer = VideoPlayer(urlAsset: fileURL, view: playerView)
            if let player = videoPlayer {
                player.playerRate = 0.67
            }
        }
    }
```

**Objective-C**

*PlayerView.h*

```
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    /*!
     @class PlayerView
     @discussion Represent View for playinv video. Layer - PlayerLayer
     @availability iOS 7 and Up
     */
    @interface PlayerView : UIView

    /*!
     @var player
     @discussion Player object
     */
    @property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;

    @end
```

*PlayerView.m*

```
    #import "PlayerView.h"

    @implementation PlayerView

    #pragma mark - LifeCycle

    + (Class)layerClass
    {
        return [AVPlayerLayer class];
    }

    #pragma mark - Setter/Getter

    - (AVPlayer*)player
    {
        return [(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] player];
    }

    - (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player
    {
        [(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] setPlayer:player];
    }

    @end
```

*VideoPlayer.h*

```
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "PlayerView.h"

    /*!
     @protocol VideoPlayerDelegate
     @discussion Events from VideoPlayer
     */
    @protocol VideoPlayerDelegate <NSObject>

    @optional

    /*!
     @brief Called whenever time when progress of played item changed
     @param progress
     Playing progress
     */
    - (void)progressDidUpdate:(CGFloat)progress;

    /*!
     @brief Called whenever downloaded item progress changed
     @param progress
     Playing progress
     */
    - (void)downloadingProgress:(CGFloat)progress;

    /*!
     @brief Called when playing time changed
     @param time
     Playing progress
     */
    - (void)progressTimeChanged:(CMTime)time;

    /*!
     @brief Called when player finish play item
    */
    - (void)playerDidPlayItem;

    /*!
     @brief Called when player ready to play item
     */
    - (void)isReadyToPlay;

    @end

    /*!
     @class VideoPlayer
     @discussion Video Player
     @code
         self.videoPlayer = [[VideoPlayer alloc] initVideoPlayerWithURL:someURL playerView:self.playerView];
         [self.videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
         self.videoPlayer.delegate = self; //optional

         //after when required play item
         [self.videoPlayer play];
     @endcode
     */
    @interface VideoPlayer : NSObject

    /*!
     @var delegate
     @abstract Delegate for VideoPlayer
     @discussion Set object to this property for getting response and notifications from this class
     */
    @property (weak, nonatomic) id <VideoPlayerDelegate> delegate;

    /*!
     @var volume
     @discussion volume of played asset
     */
    @property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat volume;

    /*!
     @var autoRepeat
     @discussion indicate whenever player should repeat content on finish playing
     */
    @property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL autoRepeat;

    /*!
     @brief Create player with asset URL
     @param urlAsset
     Source URL
     @result
     instance of VideoPlayer
     */
    - (instancetype)initVideoPlayerWithURL:(NSURL *)urlAsset;

    /*!
     @brief Create player with asset URL and configure selected view for showing result
     @param urlAsset
     Source URL
     @param view
     View on wchich result will be showed
     @result
     instance of VideoPlayer
     */
    - (instancetype)initVideoPlayerWithURL:(NSURL *)urlAsset playerView:(PlayerView *)view;

    /*!
     @brief Call this method after creating player to prepare player to play
    */
    - (void)prepareToPlay;

    /*!
     @brief Play item
     */
    - (void)play;
    /*!
     @brief Pause item
     */
    - (void)pause;
    /*!
     @brief Stop item
     */
    - (void)stop;

    /*!
     @brief Seek required position in item and pla if rquired
     @param progressValue
     % of position to seek
     @param isPlaying
     YES if player should start to play item implicity
     */
    - (void)seekPositionAtProgress:(CGFloat)progressValue withPlayingStatus:(BOOL)isPlaying;

    /*!
     @brief Player state
     @result
     YES - if playing, NO if not playing
     */
    - (BOOL)isPlaying;

    /*!
     @brief Indicate whenever player can provide CVPixelBufferRef frame from item
     @result
     YES / NO
     */
    - (BOOL)canProvideFrame;

    /*!
     @brief CVPixelBufferRef frame from item
     @result
     CVPixelBufferRef frame
     */
    - (CVPixelBufferRef)getCurrentFramePicture;

    @end
```

*VideoPlayer.m*

```
    #import "VideoPlayer.h"

    typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, InternalStatus) {
        InternalStatusPreparation,
        InternalStatusReadyToPlay,
    };

    static const NSString *ItemStatusContext;

    @interface VideoPlayer()

    @property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *assetPlayer;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) AVURLAsset *urlAsset;
    @property (strong, atomic) AVPlayerItemVideoOutput *videoOutput;

    @property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat assetDuration;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) PlayerView *playerView;

    @property (assign, nonatomic) InternalStatus status;

    @end

    @implementation VideoPlayer

    #pragma mark - LifeCycle

    - (instancetype)initVideoPlayerWithURL:(NSURL *)urlAsset
    {
        if (self = [super init]) {
            [self initialSetupWithURL:urlAsset];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (instancetype)initVideoPlayerWithURL:(NSURL *)urlAsset playerView:(PlayerView *)view
    {
        if (self = [super init]) {
            ((AVPlayerLayer *)view.layer).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
            [self initialSetupWithURL:urlAsset playerView:view];
        }
        return self;
    }

    #pragma mark - Public

    - (void)play
    {
        if ((self.assetPlayer.currentItem) && (self.assetPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)) {
            [self.assetPlayer play];
        }
    }

    - (void)pause
    {
        [self.assetPlayer pause];
    }

    - (void)seekPositionAtProgress:(CGFloat)progressValue withPlayingStatus:(BOOL)isPlaying
    {
        [self.assetPlayer pause];
        int32_t timeScale = self.assetPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale;

        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        [self.assetPlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(progressValue, timeScale) completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
            DLog(@"SEEK To time %f - success", progressValue);
            if (isPlaying && finished) {
                [weakSelf.assetPlayer play];
            }
        }];
    }

    - (void)setPlayerVolume:(CGFloat)volume
    {
        self.assetPlayer.volume = volume > .0 ? MAX(volume, 0.7) : 0.0f;
        [self.assetPlayer play];
    }

    - (void)setPlayerRate:(CGFloat)rate
    {
        self.assetPlayer.rate = rate > .0 ? rate : 0.0f;
    }

    - (void)stop
    {
        [self.assetPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
        self.assetPlayer.rate =.0f;
    }

    - (BOOL)isPlaying
    {
        return self.assetPlayer.rate > 0 ? YES : NO;
    }

    #pragma mark - Private

    - (void)initialSetupWithURL:(NSURL *)url
    {
        self.status = InternalStatusPreparation;
        [self setupPlayerWithURL:url];
    }

    - (void)initialSetupWithURL:(NSURL *)url playerView:(PlayerView *)view
    {
        [self setupPlayerWithURL:url];
        self.playerView = view;
    }

    - (void)setupPlayerWithURL:(NSURL *)url
    {
        NSDictionary *assetOptions = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : @YES };
        self.urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:assetOptions];
    }

    - (void)prepareToPlay
    {
        NSArray *keys = @[@"tracks"];
        __weak VideoPlayer *weakSelf = self;
        [weakSelf.urlAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [weakSelf startLoading];
            });
        }];
    }

    - (void)startLoading
    {
        NSError *error;
        AVKeyValueStatus status = [self.urlAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];
        if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded) {
            self.assetDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.urlAsset.duration);
            NSDictionary* videoOutputOptions = @{ (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)};
            self.videoOutput = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:videoOutputOptions];
            self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: self.urlAsset];

            [self.playerItem addObserver:self
                              forKeyPath:@"status"
                                 options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
                                 context:&ItemStatusContext];
            [self.playerItem addObserver:self
                              forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges"
                                 options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
                                 context:&ItemStatusContext];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                         name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                       object:self.playerItem];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(didFailedToPlayToEnd)
                                                         name:AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                       object:nil];

            [self.playerItem addOutput:self.videoOutput];
            self.assetPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
            [self addPeriodicalObserver];
            [((AVPlayerLayer *)self.playerView.layer) setPlayer:self.assetPlayer];
            DLog(@"Player created");
        } else {
            DLog(@"The asset's tracks were not loaded:\n%@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }

    #pragma mark - Observation

    - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    {
        BOOL isOldKey = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] isEqual:change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey]];

        if (!isOldKey) {
            if (context == &ItemStatusContext) {
                if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"] && !self.status) {
                    if (self.assetPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
                        self.status = InternalStatusReadyToPlay;
                    }
                    [self moviePlayerDidChangeStatus:self.assetPlayer.status];
                } else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"loadedTimeRanges"]) {
                    [self moviewPlayerLoadedTimeRangeDidUpdated:self.playerItem.loadedTimeRanges];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    - (void)moviePlayerDidChangeStatus:(AVPlayerStatus)status
    {
        if (status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            DLog(@"Failed to load video");
        } else if (status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
            DLog(@"Player ready to play");
            self.volume = self.assetPlayer.volume;

            if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(isReadyToPlay)]) {
                [self.delegate isReadyToPlay];
            }
        }
    }

    - (void)moviewPlayerLoadedTimeRangeDidUpdated:(NSArray *)ranges
    {
        NSTimeInterval maximum = 0;

        for (NSValue *value in ranges) {
            CMTimeRange range;
            [value getValue:&range];
            NSTimeInterval currenLoadedRangeTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(range.start) + CMTimeGetSeconds(range.duration);
            if (currenLoadedRangeTime > maximum) {
                maximum = currenLoadedRangeTime;
            }
        }
        CGFloat progress = (self.assetDuration == 0) ? 0 : maximum / self.assetDuration;
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(downloadingProgress:)]) {
            [self.delegate downloadingProgress:progress];
        }
    }

    - (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(playerDidPlayItem)]){
            [self.delegate playerDidPlayItem];
        }
        [self.assetPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
        if (self.autoRepeat) {
            [self.assetPlayer play];
        }
    }

    - (void)didFailedToPlayToEnd
    {
        DLog(@"Failed play video to the end");
    }

    - (void)addPeriodicalObserver
    {
        CMTime interval = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        [self.assetPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
            [weakSelf playerTimeDidChange:time];
        }];
    }

    - (void)playerTimeDidChange:(CMTime)time
    {
        double timeNow = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.assetPlayer.currentTime);
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(progressDidUpdate:)]) {
            [self.delegate progressDidUpdate:(CGFloat) (timeNow / self.assetDuration)];
        }
    }

    #pragma mark - Notification

    - (void)setupAppNotification
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
    }

    - (void)didEnterBackground
    {
        [self.assetPlayer pause];
    }

    - (void)willEnterForeground
    {
        [self.assetPlayer pause];
    }

    #pragma mark - GetImagesFromVideoPlayer

    - (BOOL)canProvideFrame
    {
        return self.assetPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay;
    }

    - (CVPixelBufferRef)getCurrentFramePicture
    {
        CMTime currentTime = [self.videoOutput itemTimeForHostTime:CACurrentMediaTime()];
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(progressTimeChanged:)]) {
            [self.delegate progressTimeChanged:currentTime];
        }
        if (![self.videoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:currentTime]) {
            return 0;
        }
        CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [self.videoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:currentTime itemTimeForDisplay:NULL];

        return buffer;
    }

    #pragma mark - CleanUp

    - (void)removeObserversFromPlayer
    {
        @try {
            [self.playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
            [self.playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges"];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.assetPlayer];        
        }
        @catch (NSException *ex) {
            DLog(@"Cant remove observer in Player - %@", ex.description);
        }
    }

    - (void)cleanUp
    {
        [self removeObserversFromPlayer];

        self.assetPlayer.rate = 0;
        self.assetPlayer = nil;
        self.playerItem = nil;
        self.urlAsset = nil;
    }

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [self cleanUp];    
    }

    @end
```

Off cause resource (video file) should have target membership setted to your project

[image]

Additional - [link to perfect Apple Developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW3)

Comment: Shouldn't the line `layer.player = player` (in Swift's `PlayerView`) be `layer.player = newValue`? Since you want to set the new value not the current one, which is nil.

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3**

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "small", ofType: ".mp4") {
    let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)

    let player = AVPlayer(url: filePathURL)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

None of the above worked for me **Swift 5** for Local Video Player

after reading apple documentation I was able to create simple example for playing video from Local resources

Here is code snip

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //TODO : Make Sure Add and copy "SampleVideo.mp4" file in project before play
    }

    @IBAction func playLocalVideo(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SampleVideo", ofType: "mp4") else {
            return
        }
        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the local video url path
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        present(controller, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }

}
```

> PS: Make sure you don't forget to add and copy video named
>   "SampleVideo.mp4" in project

Answer (score 5):

these code is converted code from gbk answer in swift 4

1.in your main controllview :

```
 if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clip", ofType: "mp4") {
            let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            videoPlayer = VideoPlayer(urlAsset: fileURL, view: playerView)
            if let player = videoPlayer {
                player.playerRate = 1.00
            }
        }
```

2. you need VideoPlayer class

   ```
   import AVFoundation

   import Foundation

   protocol VideoPlayerDelegate {
       func downloadedProgress(progress:Double)
       func readyToPlay()
       func didUpdateProgress(progress:Double)
       func didFinishPlayItem()
       func didFailPlayToEnd()
   }

   let videoContext:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>? = nil
   class VideoPlayer : NSObject {
       private var assetPlayer:AVPlayer?
       private var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
       private var urlAsset:AVURLAsset?
       private var videoOutput:AVPlayerItemVideoOutput?

       private var assetDuration:Double = 0
       private var playerView:PlayerView?

       private var autoRepeatPlay:Bool = true
       private var autoPlay:Bool = true

       var delegate:VideoPlayerDelegate?

       var playerRate:Float = 1 {
           didSet {
               if let player = assetPlayer {
                   player.rate = playerRate > 0 ? playerRate : 0.0
               }
           }
       }

       var volume:Float = 0 {
           didSet {
               if let player = assetPlayer {
                   player.volume = 50
               }
           }
       }

       // MARK: - Init

       convenience init(urlAsset:NSURL, view:PlayerView, startAutoPlay:Bool = true, repeatAfterEnd:Bool = true) {
           self.init()

           playerView = view
           autoPlay = startAutoPlay
           autoRepeatPlay = repeatAfterEnd

           if let playView = playerView{
               if let playerLayer = playView.layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
                   playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
               }
           }

           initialSetupWithURL(url: urlAsset)
           prepareToPlay()
       }

       override init() {
           super.init()
       }

       // MARK: - Public

       func isPlaying() -> Bool {
           if let player = assetPlayer {
               return player.rate > 0
           } else {
               return false
           }
       }

       func seekToPosition(seconds:Float64) {
           if let player = assetPlayer {
               pause()
               if let timeScale = player.currentItem?.asset.duration.timescale {
                   player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, timeScale), completionHandler: { (complete) in
                       self.play()
                   })
               }
           }
       }

       func pause() {
           if let player = assetPlayer {
               player.pause()
           }
       }

       func play() {
           if let player = assetPlayer {
               if (player.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay) {
                   player.play()
                   player.rate = playerRate
               }
           }
       }

       func cleanUp() {
           if let item = playerItem {
               item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
               item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges")
           }
           NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
           assetPlayer = nil
           playerItem = nil
           urlAsset = nil
       }

       // MARK: - Private

       private func prepareToPlay() {
           let keys = ["tracks"]
           if let asset = urlAsset {



               asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {
                   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                       // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           self.startLoading()
                       }
                   }
               })

           }
       }

       private func startLoading(){
           var error:NSError?

           guard let asset = urlAsset else {return}


   //         let status:AVKeyValueStatus = asset.statusOfValueForKey("tracks", error: &error)
      let status:AVKeyValueStatus = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "tracks", error: nil)


           if status == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded {
               assetDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)

               let videoOutputOptions = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)]
               videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: videoOutputOptions)
               playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

               if let item = playerItem {
                   item.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .initial, context: videoContext)
                   item.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: [.new, .old], context: videoContext)

                   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
                   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didFailedToPlayToEnd), name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: nil)


                   if let output = videoOutput {
                       item.add(output)

                       item.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithm.varispeed
                       assetPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

                       if let player = assetPlayer {
                           player.rate = playerRate
                       }

                       addPeriodicalObserver()
                       if let playView = playerView, let layer = playView.layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
                           layer.player = assetPlayer
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       private func addPeriodicalObserver() {
           let timeInterval = CMTimeMake(1, 1)




           if let player = assetPlayer {
               player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: timeInterval, queue:
                  DispatchQueue.main
                   , using: { (time) in
                   self.playerDidChangeTime(time: time)
               })
           }


       }

       private func playerDidChangeTime(time:CMTime) {
           if let player = assetPlayer {
               let timeNow = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
               let progress = timeNow / assetDuration

               delegate?.didUpdateProgress(progress: progress)
           }
       }

       @objc private func playerItemDidReachEnd() {
           delegate?.didFinishPlayItem()

           if let player = assetPlayer {
               player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
               if autoRepeatPlay == true {
                   play()
               }
           }
       }

       @objc private func didFailedToPlayToEnd() {
           delegate?.didFailPlayToEnd()
       }

       private func playerDidChangeStatus(status:AVPlayerStatus) {
           if status == .failed {
               print("Failed to load video")
           } else if status == .readyToPlay, let player = assetPlayer {
               volume = player.volume
               delegate?.readyToPlay()

               if autoPlay == true && player.rate == 0.0 {
                   play()
               }
           }
       }

       private func moviewPlayerLoadedTimeRangeDidUpdated(ranges:Array<NSValue>) {
           var maximum:TimeInterval = 0
           for value in ranges {
               let range:CMTimeRange = value.timeRangeValue
               let currentLoadedTimeRange = CMTimeGetSeconds(range.start) + CMTimeGetSeconds(range.duration)
               if currentLoadedTimeRange > maximum {
                   maximum = currentLoadedTimeRange
               }
           }
           let progress:Double = assetDuration == 0 ? 0.0 : Double(maximum) / assetDuration

           delegate?.downloadedProgress(progress: progress)
       }

       deinit {
           cleanUp()
       }

       private func initialSetupWithURL(url:NSURL) {
           let options = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : true]


   //        urlAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: options)
           urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url as URL, options: options)

       }

       // MARK: - Observations




       override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?){
           if (context as? UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> ) == videoContext {
               if let key = keyPath {
                   if key == "status", let player = assetPlayer {
                       playerDidChangeStatus(status: player.status)
                   } else if key == "loadedTimeRanges", let item = playerItem {
                       moviewPlayerLoadedTimeRangeDidUpdated(ranges: item.loadedTimeRanges)
                   }
               }
           }
       }


   }
   ```
3. and a PlayerView class to create a videoview:

   ```
     import AVFoundation

     import UIKit

     class PlayerView: UIView {


   override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
       get {
         return AVPlayerLayer.self
       }
   }


   var player:AVPlayer? {
       set {
           if let layer = layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
               layer.player = player
           }
       }
       get {
           if let layer = layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
               return layer.player
           } else {
               return nil
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: You have 2 retain cycles in this code. First one is in prepareToPlay, second is addPeriodicalObserver. You need to pass the self weak to the blocks.

Comment: what is videoPlayer in mainControllerView and where you define playerView?

Comment: @ChandanJee as you can see, the video player is an instance of VideoPlayer. Instead of using a local variable in that function, I have used this variable in my Class. if you want to use it in that function please write like this: var videoPlayer:VideoPlayer ...
playerView inherits from UIView. You can create a class with its name and then copy and paste the codes. after that behave with it like other views. add it in your nib or xib views

Answer (score 5):

PlayerView for **swift 4.2**

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class PlayerView: UIView {

    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    // Override UIView property
    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific and brief..!

Comment: exactly how it is done

Answer (score 3):

gbk's solution in swift 3

**PlayerView**

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class PlayerView: UIView {

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return AVPlayerLayer.self
}

var player:AVPlayer? {
    set {
        if let layer = layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
            layer.player = player
        }
    }
    get {
        if let layer = layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
            return layer.player
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
}
```

**VideoPlayer**

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

protocol VideoPlayerDelegate {
    func downloadedProgress(progress:Double)
    func readyToPlay()
    func didUpdateProgress(progress:Double)
    func didFinishPlayItem()
    func didFailPlayToEnd()
}

let videoContext:UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = nil

class VideoPlayer : NSObject {



private var assetPlayer:AVPlayer?
private var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
private var urlAsset:AVURLAsset?
private var videoOutput:AVPlayerItemVideoOutput?

private var assetDuration:Double = 0
private var playerView:PlayerView?

private var autoRepeatPlay:Bool = true
private var autoPlay:Bool = true

var delegate:VideoPlayerDelegate?

var playerRate:Float = 1 {
    didSet {
        if let player = assetPlayer {
            player.rate = playerRate > 0 ? playerRate : 0.0
        }
    }
}

var volume:Float = 1.0 {
    didSet {
        if let player = assetPlayer {
            player.volume = volume > 0 ? volume : 0.0
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Init

convenience init(urlAsset: URL, view:PlayerView, startAutoPlay:Bool = true, repeatAfterEnd:Bool = true) {
    self.init()

    playerView = view
    autoPlay = startAutoPlay
    autoRepeatPlay = repeatAfterEnd

    if let playView = playerView, let playerLayer = playView.layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    }
    initialSetupWithURL(url: urlAsset)
    prepareToPlay()
}

override init() {
    super.init()
}

// MARK: - Public

func isPlaying() -> Bool {
    if let player = assetPlayer {
        return player.rate > 0
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func seekToPosition(seconds:Float64) {
    if let player = assetPlayer {
        pause()
        if let timeScale = player.currentItem?.asset.duration.timescale {
            player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, timeScale), completionHandler: { (complete) in
                self.play()
            })
        }
    }
}

func pause() {
    if let player = assetPlayer {
        player.pause()
    }
}

func play() {
    if let player = assetPlayer {
        if (player.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay) {
            player.play()
            player.rate = playerRate
        }
    }
}

func cleanUp() {
    if let item = playerItem {
        item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
        item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges")
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    assetPlayer = nil
    playerItem = nil
    urlAsset = nil
}

// MARK: - Private

private func prepareToPlay() {
    let keys = ["tracks"]
    if let asset = urlAsset {
        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.startLoading()
            }
        })
    }
}

private func startLoading(){
    var error:NSError?
    guard let asset = urlAsset else {return}
    let status:AVKeyValueStatus = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "tracks", error: &error)

    if status == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded {
        assetDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)

        let videoOutputOptions = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)]
        videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: videoOutputOptions)
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

        if let item = playerItem {
            item.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .initial, context: videoContext)
            item.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: [.new, .old], context: videoContext)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didFailedToPlayToEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

            if let output = videoOutput {
                item.add(output)

                item.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed
                assetPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

                if let player = assetPlayer {
                    player.rate = playerRate
                }

                addPeriodicalObserver()
                if let playView = playerView, let layer = playView.layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
                    layer.player = assetPlayer
                    print("player created")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private func addPeriodicalObserver() {
    let timeInterval = CMTimeMake(1, 1)

    if let player = assetPlayer {
        player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: timeInterval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (time) in
            self.playerDidChangeTime(time: time)
        })
    }
}

private func playerDidChangeTime(time:CMTime) {
    if let player = assetPlayer {
        let timeNow = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
        let progress = timeNow / assetDuration

        delegate?.didUpdateProgress(progress: progress)
    }
}

@objc private func playerItemDidReachEnd() {
    delegate?.didFinishPlayItem()

    if let player = assetPlayer {
        player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        if autoRepeatPlay == true {
            play()
        }
    }
}

@objc private func didFailedToPlayToEnd() {
    delegate?.didFailPlayToEnd()
}

private func playerDidChangeStatus(status:AVPlayerStatus) {
    if status == .failed {
        print("Failed to load video")
    } else if status == .readyToPlay, let player = assetPlayer {
        volume = player.volume
        delegate?.readyToPlay()

        if autoPlay == true && player.rate == 0.0 {
            play()
        }
    }
}

private func moviewPlayerLoadedTimeRangeDidUpdated(ranges:Array<NSValue>) {
    var maximum:TimeInterval = 0
    for value in ranges {
        let range:CMTimeRange = value.timeRangeValue
        let currentLoadedTimeRange = CMTimeGetSeconds(range.start) + CMTimeGetSeconds(range.duration)
        if currentLoadedTimeRange > maximum {
            maximum = currentLoadedTimeRange
        }
    }
    let progress:Double = assetDuration == 0 ? 0.0 : Double(maximum) / assetDuration

    delegate?.downloadedProgress(progress: progress)
}

deinit {
    cleanUp()
}

private func initialSetupWithURL(url: URL) {
    let options = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : true]
    urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: options)
}

// MARK: - Observations

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if context == videoContext {
        if let key = keyPath {
            if key == "status", let player = assetPlayer {
                playerDidChangeStatus(status: player.status)
            } else if key == "loadedTimeRanges", let item = playerItem {
                moviewPlayerLoadedTimeRangeDidUpdated(ranges: item.loadedTimeRanges)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```