# How to create HTTP server inside iOS app that will feed the .m3u8 data to AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, http, m3u8

### How to create `HTTP server` inside iOS app to **stream & play** file `.m3u8` file

http://ccbprnrush-vh.akamaihd.net/i/PRN/premiereradionetworks/The-Rush-Limbaugh-Show/102617/80407_1509037716.12_RUSHMP320171026_,48,.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8

Answer (score 0):

1) You can play `.m3u8` data to `AVPlayer` Please view this link: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670857/streaming-m3u8-using-mpmovieplayercontroller-does-not-work)

2) >>>> **http:**//ccbprnrush-v

You can use only **https** resources.