# Adding Local files to projects files

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, video, local

[image]    import UIKit
    import AVKit
    import AVFoundation

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


var playerviewcontroller = AVPlayerViewController()
var playerview = AVPlayer ()

@IBAction func playMusic(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/MorganEvans/Documents/Apps/32134.mp4")
    playerview = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)

    playerviewcontroller.player = playerview

    self.presentViewController(playerviewcontroller, animated: true){

        self.playerviewcontroller.player?.play()
    }


}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

When I use the app it does not work because the file is on my mac. Please Can someone explain how I put the video file in the project. Thanks

Comment: add the files to project just by dragging those to the project

Answer (score 1):

You just need to drag and drop the file like video or image that you want to use in your project statically. Following i just add :

[image]

```
 @IBAction func playMusic(sender: AnyObject) {

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("32134", ofType:"mp4")
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        playerview = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)

        playerviewcontroller.player = playerview

        self.presentViewController(playerviewcontroller, animated: true){

            self.playerviewcontroller.player?.play()
        }


    }
```

---

**Another way is Past your video, audio or image file in your project folder like following:**

[image]

after that Add this file in to your xcode project by following step:

[image]

You get drapDown window and select your file as following:

[image]

And you the same code for getting file path:

```
 let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("32134", ofType:"mp4")
 let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this! I followed your instructions but et fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path) has an error. Please help

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: you need to learn it's basic thing please check this answer having nice guilde how to play mo4 file in ios swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348877/how-to-play-a-local-video-with-swift

Comment: Were you able to run the code you gave me? Because it has errors on your video too

Comment: this is command way to use local fine now you need to develop your own logic and code

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for the nil. Also get the video file URL from `NSBundle`

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("32134", ofType:"mp4") {
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    playerview = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)

    playerviewcontroller.player = playerview

    self.presentViewController(playerviewcontroller, animated: true){

        self.playerviewcontroller.player?.play()
    }
   }
```