# Play a local video automatically in in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, video

I want to play a local video ***with no controls*** in a `UIView` I have imported the frameworks AVFoundation and AVKit into my code. I have also made my class for the `UIView`, however, I am not sure on how to play the video in my `UIView` with no controls. I have already found a way to play the video from the internet and that is not what I needed.

Comment: can you please show some work? What have you written for the work to be done? Always present your work so that we can find the issue 

Look at these links 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348877/how-to-play-a-local-video-with-swift

Comment: you must go first with few tutorials like what controls are available for playing media file in your OS. Please look at these links

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/play-audio-and-video-using-avfoundation-framework-in-swift

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController

Comment: you can play local videos with AVplayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift 3.0, try this code.

```
//for Playing Video
```

@IBAction func btnvideoPlayClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
     self.videoPlay()
}

func videoPlay()
{
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.delegate = self

    let bundle = Bundle.main
    let moviePath: String? = bundle.path(forResource: "SoSorry", ofType: "mp4")
    let movieURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: moviePath!)

    let player = AVPlayer(url: movieURL)
    playerController.player = player
    self.addChildViewController(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

    player.play()

}
```

Comment: sorry but it gives me a few errors you see the class IS the UIview